# Gradient of a two-dimensionnal rect function/distribution

Tags: vector-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

In one dimension the derivative of $\operatorname{rect}_{L_x}(x)$ is given by:

$\partial_{x} \operatorname{rect}_{L_x}(x) = \delta(x+L_x/2) - \delta(x-L_x/2)$

Now I have a scalar field defined by $\operatorname{rect}$ function (rectangle distribution or potential in $x,y$ plane) of $(L_x,L_y)$ lengths:

$f(x,y) = \operatorname{rect}_{L_x} (x) \operatorname{rect}_{L_y} (y)$

I rotate the scalar field of an angle $\alpha$, that gives (in principle):

$f_{\alpha}(x,y) = \operatorname{rect}_{L_x} (\cos \alpha x + \sin \alpha y) \operatorname{rect}_{L_y} (\cos \alpha y - \sin \alpha x)$

And now I want to calculate the gradient of this function so I have:

$\vec{\nabla} f_{\alpha}(x,y) = \partial_{x} f_{\alpha}(x,y) \vec{e_x} + \partial_{y} f_{\alpha}(x,y) \vec{e_y}$

If we take just the $\vec{e_x}$ term we have, using product rule:

$\partial_{x} f_{\alpha}(x,y) = \operatorname{rect}_{L_y} (\cos \alpha y - \sin \alpha x) \partial_{x} \operatorname{rect}_{L_x} (\cos \alpha x + \sin \alpha y) + \operatorname{rect}_{L_x} (\cos \alpha x + \sin \alpha y) \partial_{x} \operatorname{rect}_{L_y} (\cos \alpha y - \sin \alpha x)$

What is the result of this partial derivative?

I would say, but I do not really know:

$\partial_{x} \operatorname{rect}_{L_x} (\cos \alpha x + \sin \alpha y) \stackrel{?}{=} \cos \alpha \left[ \delta(\cos \alpha x + \sin \alpha y + L_x/2) - \delta(\cos \alpha x + \sin \alpha y - L_x/2) \right]$

but that seems wrong because of the rotation. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are close to correct. This is what I get:
$$\begin{align}
f_\alpha(x,y) 
&= \operatorname{rect}_{L_x}(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha)
  \operatorname{rect}_{L_y}(-x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)
\\
\\
\partial_x f_\alpha(x,y)
&= (\delta_{-L_x/2}(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha)-\delta_{+L_x/2}(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha))\cos\alpha \\&\quad\quad\cdot \operatorname{rect}_{L_y}(-x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)
\\
&+ \operatorname{rect}_{L_x}(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha)
\\&\quad\quad\cdot (\delta_{-L_y/2}(-x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha) - \delta_{+L_y/2}(-x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)) (-\sin\alpha)
\\
\partial_y f_\alpha(x,y)
&= (\delta_{-L_x/2}(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha)-\delta_{+L_x/2}(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha))\sin\alpha 
\\&\quad\quad\cdot \operatorname{rect}(-x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha) \\
&+ \operatorname{rect}(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha) 
\\&\quad\quad\cdot (\delta_{-L_y/2}(-x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha) - \delta_{+L_y/2}(-x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)) \cos\alpha
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. 
With the notation $\delta_{+L_x/2}(x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha)$ you mean $\delta(x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha+L_x/2)$ (i.e translated Dirac delta on a tilted line of angle $\alpha$)?

Comment: @Fefetltl. Almost correct: $\delta_{+L_x/2}(x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha)=\delta(x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha\color{red}{-}L_x/2).$

Comment: Ok thanks md2perpe ;)